# Unix regular file

Tags: file, unix

Hello I am looking to find the regular files inside of a directory. Below is my code to do this

```
#!/bin/sh

j=0
i=0
while read dir
do
        array[ $i ]="$dir"
        (( i++ ))
done < <(ls )


for j in "${array[@]}"
do

        if [ -f "${array[j]}" ]
         then
                echo ""${j}" is a regular file"

                ((j++))

        else
                ((j++))
        fi
done
```

The problems come in my second for loop when I attempt to iterate through each entry of the array. My first problem is that even if the element in array[j] is a directory, it is still printing as a regular file. The second issue I am having is that when the loop iterates through to an element that has a file extension such as "csv.txt", the loop will stop and I will get the error

```
-bash: csv.txt: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".txt")
```

Any help would be great.

Thank you

Comment: you should better use `find /your_dir -type f` to make sure you get only files, not directories.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Clearly there are lot of problems the way you are walking through the directories and feeding into `while loop` from the output of `ls`.

Comment: My goal is to create a script that will take the contents of any directory and put them into an array. I would then like to be able sort out only the regular files from the array.